# Image is cropped when using jsoup library

Tags: android

[image]Am trying to download an image using jsoup library and set it to image view but the downloaded image is cropped automatically. i don't know if it is the library or something else. Here is my code, Any one to help me please?

```
try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document documentImage1 = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Using Elements to get the class data
            Element img = documentImage1.select("div[class=media-img imgflare--river] img[src]").first();
            // Locate the src attribute
            String imgSrcImage1 = img.attr("src");
            // Download image from URL
            InputStream inputImage1 = new java.net.URL(imgSrcImage1).openStream();
            // Decode Bitmap
            image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputImage1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[image: downloaded image]

Comment: Jsoup won't mess with the image. It'll just download what's in the HTML. How are you displaying the image? Could you show a picture of what it looks like?

Comment: check the aspect ratio of the image after downloaded

Comment: how do i check for the aspect ratio?